# I need to select a result based on 2 registers from a relation tablet. How do I do that?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
Question (id, questionText) 
QuestionCategory (id, categoryName) 
Question_QuestionCategory (questionId, categoryId)
```

Sample Data:

Table Question:

```
id  |   questionText
1   |   2 + 2 = ?
2   |   10 x 5 / 3 + 5 = ?
3   |   USA is located in which continent?
```

Table QuestionCategory:

```
id  |  categoryName
1   |  Easy
2   |  Hard
3   |  Math
4   |  Geography
```

Table Question_QuestionCategory:

```
questionId | categoryId
    1      |     1
    1      |     3
    2      |     2
    2      |     3
    3      |     1
    3      |     4
```

The Question_QuestionCategory table is a relation table that stores the foreign keys from the question and questionCategory tables.

My problem is: I need a select that returns to me a question that has the Hard and Math categories at the same time (the question with id 2 in this case). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using aggregation an checking if the distinct count of categories is equal to the number of categories you asked for. To only get one row as a result you can use `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT q.id,
       q.text
       FROM question q
            INNER JOIN question_questioncategory qc
                       ON qc.question = q.id
            INNER JOIN questioncategory c
                       ON c.id = qc.categoryid
       WHERE c.categoryname IN ('Hard',
                                'Math')
       GROUP BY q.id,
                q.text
       HAVING count(DISTINCT c.categoryname) = 2
       LIMIT 1;
```